# databricks explode dataframe with dictionary with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe in databricks:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("tom", "cat"),
        ("jerry", "mouse"),
    ],
    ["characters", "type"]
)

df.show()
```

[image]

And also the following dictionary:

```
{'leftarm':'big','rightarm':'small'}
```

I want to use explode to duplicate the dataframe by the dictionary.  But I can only get it to work if the dictionary is already part of the dataframe, like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("tom", "cat", {'leftarm':'big','rightarm':'small'}),
        ("jerry", "mouse", {'leftarm':'big','rightarm':'small'}),
    ],
    ["characters", "type", "attributes"]
)

from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df2 = df.select(df.characters,df.type,explode(df.attributes))
df2.show()
```

[image]

So my question is, is there an alternative, or do I really need to attach the dictionary to the dataframe first, and if so how?

Also is explode even the best option here in terms of performance?  I know I can use cross join but just not sure which will be quicker.

Comment: Your question is vague, What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: the issue is that I can only use explode if my dictionary is already part of dataframe, so how do can I do that?  The last code I put above does the explode fine but that's because I manipulated the dataframe so it already contains the dictionary.

Comment: Turn your dict into a dataframe and then cross join?

Comment: Yeah I've done the cross join, but I want to try explode and compare performance

Comment: Actually, if your dict is small and your original dataframe is partitioned, I do not think you can improve performance w.r.t. a broadcast join. Have you taken a look at the actual plans spark creates in the two cases you tested?